# generate table from ajax response data

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to generate table form this data using jquery. How ???

this array of data that I get from DB query

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (   [id] => 61
            [name] => Habib
            [timeview] => 3.56
            [monthnew] => july     
       )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (   [id] => 61
            [name] => Habib
            [timeview] => 2.75
            [monthnew] => august   
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (   [id] => 61
            [name] => Habib
            [timeview] => 4.81
            [monthnew] => september
        )
)
```

here is the ajax method.....

```
    ajax.done(function(data) {
        // What code should be here.....
    }
```

Comment: After json_encode what should I should do ??

Comment: provide more information, show your ajax and php handler for this exact question. Or may be you are asking how to make an ajax request and get the response?

Comment: `echo json_encode($yourArray);` will give you ability to iterate through your array using `for` loop in ajax response

Comment: After json_encode

[{"id":"61","name":"Habib","timeview":3.56,"monthnew":"july "},{"id":"61","name":"Habib","timeview":2.76,"monthnew":"august "},{"id":"61","name":"Habib","timeview":"4.80","monthnew":"september"}]

Comment: `console.log(response)` on ajax success and show me how it is look

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this : $table would be the table you're appending to. Let me know if you want some more details

```
 $table = jQuery('#table');

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "your-script.php",
      success: function (data) {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
          $table.append("<tr>" + data[i].text + "</tr>");
        }
      }
    });
```

(ref : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)